# string search using OQL

Tags: visualvm, jvisualvm, oql

I am using VisualVM to analyze a core dump. I suspect some XML objects to be causing the leak but there are way too many String objects to go through one by one.

Can I use OQL to search String that begin with 'GH' ?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this: 
`select {instance: s, content: s.toString()} from java.lang.String s where s.count>2 && s.toString().substring(0,2)=="GH"`

Answer (score 32):

under JDK 1.8.20 a more simple variant works:

```
select s from java.lang.String s where s.toString().startsWith("GH")
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Where do you find documentation for all the supported methods? Googling only leads to random blogs that don't work

Comment: just looked at the answer below and guessed that startsWith could work. also as I heard it's possible to use sql with a heap dump

Answer (score 6):

```
heap.objects('java.lang.String', false, "it.toString().startsWith('GH')")
```

Comment: A short ummary would help reviewers (like me) to judge the validity of your answer; interested users wouldn't have to dive into the code to understand your appoach. Just a sentence or two would be fine and not too much work.

Answer (score -1):

select c.attr_name.toString() from a.b.c.MyClass c where c.attr_name.toString().startsWith("GH")